# System V Message Queue Trouble

Tags: c++, linux, posix, ipc, message-queue

I am having a bit of trouble getting a System V Message Queue setup and working properly on Linux. The idea is to get a central node to pull data from several other nodes. The trouble is that the central node ends up sitting there waiting for the other nodes to send messages. I have looked at the values for the mailboxes and they are the same across all processes. I.E. 0 for the central mailbox, 32769 for other process 1, ect. I have no idea on why it appears to fail. I have tried to change the priority parameter in msgrcv to 0 to accept all incoming messages and the same issue occurs. Any help would be much appriciated. (Sorry for the lack of comments.)

Here is the code for the central node:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

struct{
    long priority;
    int temperature;
    int pid;
    int stable;
} msgp;

const int mainMailID = 8484;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

//declare needed variables
int centralMailID;
int externalMailID[4];
int tempdata;
int externalTempature[4];
int externalTemperatureLast[4];

//set initial values for msgp
msgp.priority = 2;
msgp.temperature = atoi(argv[1]);
msgp.pid = 0;
msgp.stable = 0;

//create the central mailbox
centralMailID = msgget(mainMailID, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);

if(centralMailID == -1){
    cout << "Message Queue Creation Failed" << endl;

}
else{
    cout << "Message Queue Created" << endl;
}

//create the external mailboxes
for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){

    externalMailID[i] = msgget(mainMailID + i+1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);

    if(externalMailID[i] == -1){
        cout << "Message Queue " << i << " Creation Failed" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Message Queue " << i << " Created" << endl;
    }
}

printf("%i", externalMailID[0]);

while(msgp.stable == 0){

    int centralTemperature = msgp.temperature;

    //get the tempatures from the external sensors.
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){

        tempdata = msgrcv(externalMailID[i], &msgp, sizeof(msgp)-sizeof(long), 2, 0);

        cout << "Recived data from sensor " << msgp.pid << endl;

        externalTempature[i] = msgp.temperature;
    }

    if(externalTempature[0] == externalTempature[1] == externalTempature[2] == externalTempature[3] == centralTemperature){

        msgp.stable = 1;
        continue; //could also use break
    }

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){

        sum = sum + externalTempature[i];
    }

    centralTemperature = ((2 * centralTemperature) + sum)/6;
    msgp.temperature = centralTemperature;

    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){

        tempdata = msgsnd(externalMailID[i], &msgp, sizeof(msgp)-sizeof(long), 0);

        printf("Sent data to external mailbox %i", i);
    }
}
printf("Process ended");
return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for the other nodes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

struct{
    long priority;
    int temperature;
    int pid;
    int stable;
} msgp;

const int mainMailID = 8484;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


int centralMailID = msgget(mainMailID, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
int pid = atoi(argv[2]);
int externalMailID = msgget(mainMailID + pid, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
int externalTemperature = atoi(argv[1]);
int tempdata;

cout << externalMailID << endl;

msgp.priority = 2;

msgp.pid = pid;
msgp.stable = 0;

while(msgp.stable == 0){

    msgp.temperature = externalTemperature;

    tempdata = msgsnd(centralMailID, &msgp, sizeof(msgp)-sizeof(long), 0);

    tempdata = msgrcv(externalMailID, &msgp, sizeof(msgp)-sizeof(long), 2, 0);

    externalTemperature = ((externalTemperature * 3) + (msgp.temperature * 2))/5;

    if(msgp.stable == 1){

        continue;
    }
}

printf("Child Process Ended");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the system V api, which is probably not what you want. See here for more details:

http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/unixprg/#ipc__posix_msgqs

---

The msgget, msgctl, msgsnd, msgrcv commands are part of the older, system V api, and while the semantics are similar, are not posix queues. A couple of quick google search for system V queue tutorials/examples are likely to solve your problem.

If you're genuinely looking to use posix queues, switch to and look for documentation on the mq_open, mq_close, mq_unlink, mq_send, mq_receive, mq_getattr, mq_setattr api.

Comment: Please restate the essentials from the given link. Link only answers aren't useful for SO, since links tend to rot.

Comment: Why do you assume System V API is not what the OP wants? These APIs are still being taught at many unversities.

Comment: he explicitly states that he's using posix queues, but his code shows system V queues. if he's being taught posix queues, he's using the wrong api. if he's being taught system V queues, he's asking the wrong question.

Comment: I am just going by what my instructor and book have stated. They used the api and functions that I am using and referred to them as PSOIX. I suppose I was incorrect about what it is called, as System V is what I must use.